# Isolating variables in system of equations with Sympy

Tags: sympy

Consider the parameterization for a circle given by

```
import sympy as sp
sp.var('x,y,theta,r')
e1 = sp.Eq(r, sp.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))
e2 = sp.Eq(theta, sp.atan2(y,x))
```

How do I get Sympy to give me the same thing but in terms of `x` and `y`? Namely, I want this:

```
x = r*cos(theta)
y = r*sin(theta)
```

But when I use Sympy solve what I get is

```
[(-sqrt(r**2*cos(theta)**2), sqrt(r**2)*sin(theta)),
 (sqrt(r**2*cos(theta)**2), sqrt(r**2)*sin(theta))]
```

Even when I when the second solution, I still can't make Sympy simplify `sqrt(r**2)` for `r`.

Thanks

Comment: `sqrt(r**2)` *does not* equal `r`, in general. See the discussion [here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/simplification.html#powers) (in particular, identity 3)

Comment: @Stelios Yeah, but it does in this case. So I'd like to know how I tell Sympy that x and y are real, so that r is always positive

Comment: Define your symbols as `r = sp.symbols('r', positive = True)` and `x, y = sp.symbols('x, y', real = True)`, instead of using `var` which implies that the symbols are complex valued.

Comment: @Stelios I did not know that, If you turn that into an answer I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`solve` (or the newer `solveset`) is what you want to isolate variables.

As pointed out in the comments, you need to set `r` as positive for `sqrt(r**2)` to simplify to `r`

```
r = symbols('r', positive=True)
```